# Cannot connect to target : STlink V3 not connecting to Nucleo Board using SWD

Tags: debugging, embedded, stm32, stm32f1, st-link

I am using STLink V3 set to program the F103RB Nucleo board using SWDIO interface. The board works fine when connected to PC using the on-board STlink debugger but when I use external STlink device to program it, it says "Can not connect to target!". I have removed on-board STlink debugger jumpers so that I can use external one. My connection from Stlink V3 to F103RB Nucleo (CN4 Header)
are as follows:
Clock->Clock,     GND->GND,   SWDIO->SWDIO,    NRST->NRST,VCC->NOT CONNECTED  (Even if I connect, it doesn't work)

The datasheet says that "SB12 NRST (target MCU RESET) must be OFF if CN4 pin 5 is used in the external application", is this the problem ? How to resolve that ? or is there any other potential reason for this error.

I'll really appreciate prompt responses. Thanks

Comment: This is not the place for this question - it is not an issue with your code.  The the appropriate stack exchange site would be https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CN4 connector is connected to on-board ST-LINK, which is used when you use on-board ST-LINK to program/debug an external device.

You need to access pins of the main uC using other connectors.

Please see this answer:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/566511/how-can-i-program-a-stm32-nucleo-board-without-using-the-on-board-st-link/566515#566515

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. I was mixing that on-board debugger with the external one. Thanks for prompt response

Comment: @Noman Then please mark this answer as the *accepted answer* by clicking on the *check* button on the left of the answer.